# Restoring vintage road bike - need help with brake choice/compatibility

Tags: road-bike, brakes, vintage

I'm restoring this old bike that I found on the road side :). I can afford to get this one stolen.. unlike my beloved Trek Checkpoint.

First thing is going to be the brakes. These look like side-pull brakes. Anyone got any tips about what might be compatible? Not sure if all brake calipers will have a long enough thread. Also, is there a standard thread thickness?

Any help much appreciated!

[image: Bike]

[image: Rear]

[image: Rear 2]

Comment: Likely almost anything. The length of the brake arms will be important. These look like ready for big tyres.

Comment: First remove the brakes, take them apart, clean and grease. They might still be usable with new blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The brake assembly looks good in your bike. May be some cleaning should do. The side pulls are easy to balance, in my experience, may be I am still a old school guy. The wheel rim looks like a steel one and my two cents would be stay with side pulls.

As to the brake pads, if you're planning on to use the same steel rims go for brake pads which are hard (and last long at the cost of relatively less breaking power) as opposed to medium brake pads for aluminum rims.

Coming to length and thickness: Length is typically 70 mm for V-brake types and from the picture if I am not wrong, yours are 55 mm. I would stay with 55 mm. Thickness typically maxes at 10 mm.

Comment: Although the bolt that attaches the brake to the bridge looks as if it has lost some threading just behind the nut. But if the thread is sound under the nut it is merely a cosmetic problem. Else you LBS might have a replacement in their odd bits and parts bin.